# determine the points at which f has partial derivatives

Tags: real-analysis, partial-derivative

Let be $f : \mathbb R^2 \rightarrow  \mathbb R$
$$f(x,y)=\cases{2-xy,& if $ x,y \in \mathbb Q $\\ xy, & otherwise }$$
Determine the points at which f has partial derivatives.
ATTEMPT:
Suppose that partial derivatives exist at the point $(x_0,y_0)$.Case 1: $x_0,y_0 \in Q$.
By definition
$$f_x(x_0,y_0)= \lim_{x\rightarrow x_0} \frac{f(x,y_0)-f(x_0,y_0)}{x-x_0} $$
Since $\mathbb Q^2$ is dense,there exists $(x_k)\subset \mathbb Q^2$ such that $x_k \rightarrow x_0$.

$$f_x(x_0,y_0)= \lim_{k\rightarrow \infty} \frac{f(x_k,y_0)-f(x_0,y_0)}{x-x_0} $$
$$f_x(x_0,y_0)= -y_0  $$

But if I take the limit with a succession of irrational numbers, I don't conclude anything.

Comment: Well, $\mathbb{R}^2\setminus \mathbb{Q}^2$ is also dense. So you can run the same argument, which yields a different expression. This allows you then to determine at which points the partial derivatives exist.